Is the annihilator of a left ideal $I$ a submodule?
I was working on Exercise 6.17 from Chapter III of Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 textbook. The statement of the exercise is included in the image attached below.

I also included the statement of Exercise 6.16 to show that when the author talks about a cyclic $R$-module (and, in general, when he mentions an $R$-module), he refers to a left $R$-module. Exercise 6.17 is not difficult to solve as long as the set $\{ n \in N | (\forall a \in I), an = 0 \}$ is a left $R$-module or a submodule of the left $R$-module $N$.
However, since $I$ is just a left-ideal of $R$, how do we know that this set is indeed a submodule of $N$? My issue is showing that it is closed under scalar products because if $n \in N$ is such that $an = 0$ for any $a \in I$, given $r \in R$, we'd like to show that $rn$ is such that $a(rn) = (ar)n = 0$ for any $a \in I$, but we don't know whether $ar$ is an element of $I$ or not because $I$ is not a right-ideal of $R$ and $R$ is not assumed to be commutative. Am I confusing myself or missing something? Or is there another argument to show that the set in question is indeed a submodule of $N$?

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is the explanation why.

The set $\text{Hom}_{R\textsf{-Mod}}(M,N)$ is, in general, not an $R$-module, only an abelian group.
Therefore, we should not expect that $\{n \in N : (\forall a \in I) \  an=0\}$ is an $R$-module.
Thus, exercise 6.16 only asks you to prove that
$$
\text{Hom}_{R\textsf{-Mod}}(M,N) \cong \{n \in N : (\forall a \in I) \ an=0\}
$$
as abelian groups.

It is also an isomorphism of left $R$-modules when $I$ is a two-sided ideal. In that case, $R/I$ is a bimodule, and then the hom-group is actually a left $R$-module. Also, it was explained by the OP why the annihilator is a submodule.

@MartinBrandenburg Right. Thanks!
